# Elementor: a page suddenly changed to type of Post incorrectly

Tags: elementor

I picked the `events` page and edited it:

[image]

Then i found it had become a type of `Post` incorrectly:

[image]

That was really weird.

Does anybody know something about it?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to a client when they had a post category or post by the same name. Let me know that is the case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not this case. There is no post or post category with the same name